# Do not disturb by time per application

Tags: macos, notifications

Is there any way to disable notification only with specific application(s) for a certain time **(not permanently)**? Something like Do Not Disturb, but for specific application(s). Or maybe even by notification banners?

Usually I need this for disable notifications for skype or other messenger apps for hour, so that I won't forget to turn notifications back on.

Comment: iOS doesn't have this feature yet, but maybe a third-party app does?

Comment: This would be awesome!